# Cant prove this inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Why does $\ln\left(\frac{\left(k+1\right)\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}}{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}}\right) \ge \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}\left(k+1\right)}$

Im in a middle of a guided proof about Dirichlet's kernel when i need to show that $L_1\to \infty$ to the left side of the inequality is a lower bound to $||D_N||_1$

This is the full try for some context

$\left|\left|D_{N}\right|\right|_{1} \ge 2\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\int\limits _{k\pi}^{\left(k+1\right)\pi}\left|\frac{\sin\left(u\right)}{u}\right|du=\ge2\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\int\limits _{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\left(k+1\right)\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}}\left|\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{u}\right|du=2\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\limits _{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\left(k+1\right)\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}}\left|\frac{1}{u}\right|du\right)$

$2\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\left|\ln\left(u\right)\right|\right]_{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\left(k+1\right)\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)=2\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\left(k+1\right)\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\ln\left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$

$2\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{\left(k+1\right)\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}}{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln\left(\frac{\left(k+1\right)\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}}{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}}\right) =\ln\left(1+\frac2{4k+1}\right)\sim \frac1{2k}.$

As $\frac12>\frac1{2\sqrt2}$ the  desired inequality holds for sufficiently large $k.$

Comment: Does $\ln\left(1+\frac2{4k+1}\right)\sim \frac1{2k}$ true only when $k \to \infty$ ?  and $\ln\left(1+\frac2{4k+1}\right)\ge \frac1{2k}$ or it may be $\le$ ? 
Thanks

Comment: $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ when $x\to0$ and obviously $\frac{2}{4k+1}\sim \frac1{2k}$

Comment: $\ln(1+x)<x$ and $\frac{2}{4k+1}<\frac{1}{2k}$ but this does not in any way affect the inequality $\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{4k+1}\right)>\frac{1}{ck}$ for sufficiently large $k$ if $c>2$ .